# hosting people asking for my account username and password to enable curl and socket function only for me

Tags: socket, security

I have hosted my site in a shared environment. 
My hosting people disabled socket function all together.
and they said that we can enable only for you if i given a written statement.
I did but they asked for my control panel login details so they will run some kind of script to enable it.

Is it right for the hosting company to ask for credentials.

They have the total control so why cant they do it?

**Edit:**

Before six months many websites in their server got hacked.

So they think it would be because of socket functions and had disabled it.

They say they can enable it for specific users who do programming using that and that is by email request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are asking these things I can only think of two reasons:

1. This is not your hosting company, but some social engineers. Your hosting company should indeed be able to get to your username and at least to be  able reset your password temporarily or use a master account.
2. They are incompetent and I suggest you go looking for another hosting provider.

Comment: Furthermore, if they need access to *your* control panel to enable it, you would be able to simply run the same script and enable it yourself.  I'm leaning towards 2.

Comment: There is a third option (though it is no better).  They are an ultra-budget host with outsourced support which the hosting company has not granted administrative access to.

Comment: i have updated my question to give more details. They are the hosting company and had disabled for all people... please read the edit section of the question. :)

Comment: They got hacked by someone using sockets (seems very weird to me)? Anyway that still doesn't make sense why they would need your password :). I think they are telling you a lot of bull. Get to a new hosting provider because these guys don't really know what they are doing.